# Hyper-V Virtualization for Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-phone, virtualization, hyper-v

I'm just trying to enable the Hyper-V but I have the problem that **when I enable from Bios**, **I can't enable it from** *"Turn Windows features on/off"* because after **restarting, my laptop stay on the loading icon and got frozen for ever**. When I first enable it from the *"Turn Windows features on/off"* and restart, all going great. But when I now enable Virtualization from BIOS, I have the same issue.

The case is that I can't have this two at the same time enabled, because when restarting, it hangs.

I will put here the images, that my laptop support the virtualization:

[image]

[image]

My laptop you can see all the specification here: http://store.hp.com/GermanyStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=F1Y49EA&opt=ABD&sel=PCNB

Only that I install the Windows 8 Pro Student version because this is only compatible to Hyper-V. I successfully install all the drivers and theoretically enabling Hyper-V must work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to update BIOS. It's helped to me.

Comment: The Update doesn't help me too.